# Freelance : discussing code source application

Tags: freelancing

I freelance for a client to develop a web application, I want to know if it is normal to give him the source code of the application, or to discuss this code line by line with me, what you think about this situation ?

Thank you very much

Comment: @JoeStrazzere ok , but I think it's not normal to disscus my code , it can only disscus fonctionalities of this application ???

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Wouldn't that depend on the contract? It depends on whether the code is sold or licensed. But irrespective of that, I agree, what's the problem talking line by line with the client?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on programmers or Freelance.  It is not about navigating the workplace

Comment: Related question:  http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/what-to-do-with-code-after-job-completion

Answer (score 3):

You need to bill for this discussion time since it is not typical and will be very lengthy. Often, gather enough requirements to do a quote is not directly billed/itemized, but ends up in the over-all fee eventually.

Everything is negotiable. The client needs to be aware that this will slow the project down and take up your time which you do not intend to do for free.

If it takes too much of your time (Maybe you have another project) you can decline to do the code review or the entire project.

My guess is this client wants to play it safe and make sure they understand the code in case you leave, start charging too much, fail to complete the project, etc.